# Scala nest data structure

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to scala programming language

In java if I have a data structure like `HashMap<Integer,HashSet<LinkedList>>`

If I don't initialize HashSet, I will get NullpointerException.

But in Scala, if I have `HashMap<Int,HashSet<ListBuffer[Int]>>`

How do  I initialize nested HashSet?

When I use get() method.Should I use pattern match like

case Some =>

case None =>

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching as you describe is a good option.

An other one is to use [`getOrElse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map@getOrElse(key:A,default:=%3EB):B):

```
map.getOrElse(10, Set.empty)
```